# Nested bash loop runs but logic is not correct

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, nested-loops

I have this nested bash for loop where the first loop represents the range of servers, and the second loop reads each lines of the .txt file. Then will do a zgrep -i and find for a string on the matching line.

keys.txt is as follow:

```
1121313232323-1
1121313244234-1
1121867575757-1
```

Bash Loops:

```
for i in {1..80}; do for j in `cat keys.txt`; do zgrep -i 'InitialRequest' /var/logs/server$i/* >> /var/log/result.log; done; done &
```

This runs but its logging every instance where 'InitialRequest' is defined. What im looking for is to only log lines where the key line is matched to 'InitialRequest' with their key value.

The result i'm expecting is like this (with Key value from J inner loop 1121313232323-1 and with string 'InitialRequest' plus the remaining of the line:

```
1121313232323-1 InitialRequest http://someramdomurl.com
```

What I'm getting is like (just the matching string without the Key value from the J inner loop:

```
InitialRequest http://someramdomurl.com
InitialRequest http://someotherramdomurl.com
InitialRequest http://someotherotherramdomurl.com
```

Can anyone advise where is my error?

Comment: what's the purpose of the inner `for` loop since you never reference `$j`? please update the question with some sample data from one of the log files, the (wrong) output from your script, and the (correct) expected output

Comment: Yes, you are right that is what is happening. I updated my question.  How should I specify the j loop in this case?

Comment: but... just `zgrep -f keys.txt -i /var/logs/server{1..80}/*`.. `ow should I specify the j loop in this case?` What do you want to do with `$j`? You want to _prepend output of grep_ with the content of `$j` variable? What is the point of `keys.txt` if you do not use it's content?

Comment: @KamilCuk Correct that is my mistake. The purpose of the inner loop J is to read each line of the .txt file and match 'stringtomatch' on the same line using zgrep. This is going to look across many servers, so what's why i used 1..80 on the outter loop.

Comment: Backticks have been obsolete for command substitution for several decades.   Disregarding the advisability of writing the loop this way at all, you should use a more modern notation: `for j in $(cat keys.txt)`

Comment: How does the line from `keys.txt` relate to the output in your example? In other words, how did you know that `1121313232323-1` was associated with `http://someramdomurl.com` as opposed to some other match?

Comment: @eewanco - I modified the description a bit to attempt to make it clear. To answer your question, It's because it is looking through various log lines. For example in the first match (the result I want), 1121313232323-1 is matched to http://somerandomurl.com because the string 'InitialRequest' is found on the same line. As opposed to the second match, InitialRequest is getting logged regardless since the key value is not being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not `zgrep`ing `$j` in the files. For better clarity I will replace `$i` with `$server` and `$j` with `$key` in my answer. Check it out:

```sh
for server in server{1..80}; do
    for key in $(cat keys.txt); do
        zgrep -i "$key InitialRequest" /var/logs/$server/* >>/var/log/result.log
    done
done
```

But since you are always using the same keys, you just need to read them once. Here is a better version:

```sh
keys=($(cat keys.txt))

for server in server{1..80}; do
    for key in ${keys[*]}; do
        zgrep -i "$key InitialRequest" /var/logs/$server/* >>/var/log/result.log
    done
done
```